# How to browse class hierarchy with slime in common-lisp

Tags: common-lisp, clos

I'm using emacs,+slime+sbcl.

I can go up a class hierarchy while I inspect a class/object through the slime-inspector.
But how can I browse subclasses of a specific class ?
Is there a slime function (or another way) to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it should appear in the `DIRECT-SUBCLASSES` slot in the inspector.

In case you don't see it, it might be because your Slime inspector isn't *fancy*:

```
(setq slime-contribs '(slime-fancy))
```

Or just call <kbd>M-x slime-enable-contrib</kbd> followed by `fancy`, which enables all fancy features (technically `fancy-inspector` should be enough).

You can also do it in your programs by using Closer MOP:

```
(closer-mop:class-direct-subclasses (find-class 'number))
=> (#<BUILT-IN-CLASS COMMON-LISP:COMPLEX> #<BUILT-IN-CLASS COMMON-LISP:REAL>)
```